# ExtJS 3. Append configs dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

Is there any way to apend some configs (object properties) to created extobject.

```
var thePanel = new Ext.Panel({
   border: false
});

thePanel.addpendConfigs({               //How to?
   height: 40,
   region: "north"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Ext.applyIf`. 
From the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/?class=Ext)

> Copies all the properties of config to obj if they don't already
>   exist.

Here's the definition:

```
applyIf( Object obj, Object config ) : Object
```

Otherwise use the Ext.apply

> Copies all the properties of config to obj.

Definition:

```
apply( Object obj, Object config, Object defaults ) : Object
```

Answer (score 2):

i'm guessing from setting the region north that you wan't to add the panel to a container with border layout ... I believe you can do something like

```
thePanel.setHeight(40);
thePanel.region = 'north';

container.add(thePanel);
container.doLayout();
```

dolayout method should force the recalculation of the layout on all the components ...

**Edit:**

For the universal solution check Ext.apply

```
var config = {
   height: 40,
   region: "north"
}

Ext.apply(thePanel,config);
```

But i think you still need to force the layout recalculation like above

Comment: thx for quick answer. but i'm looking for universal solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, once the object has been instantiated, you cannot simply whack new config options into it. It bubbles too much ( eg, say for example you want to overwrite the "items" array, this affects quite a bit of your actual object ).

Generally ExtJs has a method to do what you want to do however.